# How to avoid locking in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which has concurrent reads as and also some part of the application updating the same collection but during the load each read and update operation taking so much of time and it gets very slow with time

---

Here is log of some query

```
nscanned:4 nupdated:2 keyUpdates:3 numYields: 1 locks(micros) w:2475463 10247ms
nscanned:4 nupdated:2 keyUpdates:2 numYields: 1 locks(micros) w:2077481 1054ms
```

Collection has only 70K records.
Concurrent read and writes are almost 10.

This is what I have already done

1. Sharding with 3 member replica set
2. Sharding key is hashed and both db and collection level sharding is enble
3. Each replica box is has enough power and ram .
4. Query are bounded with index and `db.collection.find().explain()` has this output

   ```
   {
       "cursor" : "BtreeCursor fp.ulc_1_c_1_p_1",
       "isMultiKey" : true,
       "n" : 0,
       "nscannedObjects" : 2,
       "nscanned" : 2,
       "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
       "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
       "scanAndOrder" : false,
       "indexOnly" : false,
       "nYields" : 0,
       "nChunkSkips" : 0,
       "millis" : 0,
       "indexBounds" : {
           "fp.ulc" : [
               [
                   "0ca01c47c984b5583d455e42aafded2c",
                   "0ca01c47c984b5583d455e42aafded2c"
               ]
           ],
           "c" : [
               [
                   false,
                   false
               ]
           ],
           "p" : [
               [
                   1372062247612,
                   1.7976931348623157e+308
               ]
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

I have also tried to set read preference with secondary but after a period of time it also goes slow
Also I have noticed lock in mongostat here is output from mongostat

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults       locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn  set repl       time
    *0     *0      6     *0       4     2|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.74g      0 collectDb:199.7%          0       6|0     0|1     3k   130k    21 set1  PRI   08:27:55
    *0     *0     15     *0      11     8|0       1  54.4g   109g  1.74g      0 collectDb:200.1%          0       6|0     0|1    11k   357k    21 set1  PRI   08:27:58
     7     *0     34     *0      18    26|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.75g      0 collectDb:202.9%          0       6|0     0|1    36k   362k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:00
     1     *0     13     *0       8     7|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.75g      0 collectDb:192.3%          0       6|0     0|1    12k   287k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:03
     1     *0      9     *0       7     8|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.75g      0 collectDb:196.1%          0       6|0     0|1     5k   258k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:04
     5     *0     20     *0      10    13|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.75g      0 collectDb:207.7%          0       6|0     0|1    23k   214k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:08
     8     *0     38     *0      21    29|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.74g      0 collectDb:215.9%          0       5|0     0|1    40k   548k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:12
     6     *0     44     *0      24    22|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.75g      0 collectDb:199.5%          0       3|0     0|1    45k   509k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:15
     2      4     27     *0      11    28|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.75g      0 collectDb:169.2%          0       6|0     0|1    21k   318k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:18
     2     *0     29     *0      18    20|0       0  54.4g   109g  1.74g      0 collectDb:255.5%          0       5|0     0|1    28k   588k    21 set1  PRI   08:28:24
```

Comment: what kind of updates are being done? are they adding new fields or just replacing existing ones?

Comment: They are adding new keys in an existing document

Comment: what exactly do you mean by adding new keys? could you elaborate a little please. Thanks

Comment: i hv a document like this { a:1 , b:[{c:1},{d:1}]} and next time i push some object inside b .

Comment: The reason could be because in MongoDB the document is allocated/padded with a certain amount of space in RAM so that it need not be fetched from disk. But when you add new fields (such as the ones added into b array) then sometimes the document grows more than the allocated space and hence it writes the document to disk. This causes the blocking inconsistency. You can try to store all the values that you are going to add in a data structure and then write a script to update the MongoDB document. This would be called in-place updates. This would be useful to do. All the best.

Comment: yes i got this i have updated my EC2 with higher iops but i think db level locking is main issue.what i hv figured out to separate these two collection on two different dbs avoid locking issue of entire db for read and write but if locking is done at collection level so it may avoid many lock % and finally increase the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i finally figured out some best way to avoid locking in mongodb.

What i did

- Updated my mongodb to latest stable production release 2.4.8 [from here](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads).
- Updated my ebs to optimized iops 2000 with [Raid 10 ebs](http://blog.9minutesnooze.com/raid-10-ebs-data/).
- Monitored my slow queries from mongod.log file and also iowait for each drive.
- Added some multikey index and compound indexs [From Mongodb indexs docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/).
- And also i watched the consumption of ram on each ec2 instance including primary and secondary member of replica set.
- [Change the instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html) type to Ebs optimized with Gigabit Ethernet interface and more than 16 gb of ram on each server so that most of the time ram is available for index and current data set .
- A good to read [Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) for amazon instance and their best use case so that you can understand your requirement better.

---

Although locking is a major issue in MongoDB but i think they are working on collection level locking so may be in the upcoming version it will solve almost everything related to performance degrade due to locking.
Here is the [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1240) link you can check the status.